# Prove that every graph has two vertices that are endpoints of the same number of edges

Tags: graph-theory

> Prove that every graph has two vertices that are endpoints of the same number of edges.

My proof was that in any graph with $n$ vertices, each vertex $v$ has have $1 \leq \deg(v) \leq n-1$. By a simple argument with pigeonhole it is seen that since there are $n$ vertices at least $2$ of them must have the same degree.

This proof seemed to easy to me, so I wanted to know if I made a mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is the main idea of the proof.  However, in principle, the $n$ degrees could be $0,1,2,\ldots,n-1$, which are all different.  If you can explain why this case is impossible, you will have completed the proof.

Good luck!

Comment: Hint: assume the contrary, i.e. let $G$ be a graph where all vertices have different degrees. Can you see why this leeds to something wrong?