# A graph with $100$ vertices

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, pigeonhole-principle

I am learning some discrete mathematics and stuck on following problem :

Let $G$ be a graph with $100$ vertices prove/disprove that there are two vertices with same degree.

I know that for a given vertex  $v$ there are $99$ choices for a neighbor of this vertex hence degree  ${\rm deg}_{G}(V) \le 99$

But after this I don't know how should I proceed ?

Comment: It looks like a job for the pigeonhole principle

Comment: $100$ is arbitrary. The proof for general $n$ is very similar. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2690150/proving-that-in-a-simple-graph-with-n-vertices-two-vertices-have-the-same-deg, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1636996/prove-that-every-graph-has-two-vertices-that-are-endpoints-of-the-same-number-of for essentially the same proof.

Comment: A good title should give the reader some idea what the question is about. I'm sure you thought hard about that, and "A graph with $100$ vertices" was the best you could come up with. It seems to me that something like "Two vertices with the same degree" would work better, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: Note that this assumes the graph is loopless (no edges connect a vertex to itself). In a graph where loops are allowed, it is obviously disprovable.